# How do evalutar a complex number and its conjugate squared sum?

Tags: complex-numbers

Given $z= x + i y$, let $z' = x - i y $ be the complex conjugate of $z$.

How can I evaluate $(z + z')^2$? I would like to expand the bracket and use the notation $R e^{i \theta}$ but I don't know how.

Comment: where is the square of the title? And, $z+z'$ is simply $2x$.

Comment: Ops sorry, I edited the question

Comment: Anyway, $z+z'=2x$ so the square is $4x^2$.

Comment: Yes but I was interested in demonstrating it using the $R e^{i \theta}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

If you want to use the polar form, note that $z=r e^{i \theta}\Rightarrow z'=r e^{-i \theta}$ and:

$$
e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}=(\cos \theta + i \sin \theta)+(\cos (-\theta) + i \sin (-\theta))=(\cos \theta + i \sin \theta)+(\cos \theta - i \sin \theta) =2\cos \theta
$$

because $\cos(-\theta)=\cos \theta$ and $\sin(-\theta)=-\sin\theta$.

Comment: Could you explain the second hint?

Comment: I've added. I hope it's helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Notice, assume $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$:

- $x+yi=|x+yi|e^{\arg(x+yi)i}=\text{R}e^{\Phi i}$

$$\left(z+z'\right)^2=\left(x+yi+x-yi\right)^2=(x+x)^2=(2x)^2=4x^2$$

Comment: This does not use the polar form, that the OP requested.

Comment: @Did Why are you going off all my answer and downvoting it? Realy realy bad, I did what I could!